# Fantasy novel with three families, Porta, Gates, and Janus

Tags: story-identification

It was a print novel, in English. I barely remember the details. There were three families besides the family of the main character, whose last names were Porta, Gates, and Janus. The main character was a girl, either in junior high or high school, who might have been named Bianca. All I can remember of the plot (don't take this for granted, though: I have a terrible memory) is that she found some sort of egg which stuck itself on her arm and fused with her.

I would be grateful if someone could tell me the title or author.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Thresholds*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7658462-thresholds) (Magic Next Door #1) by Nina Kiriki Hoffman

Maya moves to a new town, next to an apartment building named Janus House. Porta, Gates, and Janus are families that live there and help manage the portal to elsewhere in the building's basement.

From a review at Goodreads:

> ...there is an inter world emergency involving eggs of alien life
>   forms being stolen. The masterminds behind this are an alien life form
>   who basically want to take over. One of these eggs is implanted on
>   Maya's wrist and bonds with her which basically means it's hers for life.

[image]